# How to keep xfoil open using subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

#### Summary

I am automating [xfoil](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/) with the `subprocess` module.  I would like to be able to start an xfoil session with several commands and leave it open for the user to take on.
This would help debugging and also more generally to have a basic routine to start xfoil (without manually typing the same set of commands every time).

I am able to run any xfoil command using `subprocess.communicate()`.
However, when open with `subprocess` xfoil systematically closes without user action.

#### Example

With the following code, you can see xfoil opening and closing quickly.

```py
import subprocess

XFOIL_PATH = 'xfoil.exe'

xfoil = subprocess.Popen(XFOIL_PATH, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         universal_newlines=True)

actions = 'NACA 0012\nGDES\n'
xfoil.communicate(input=actions)
```

#### Note

I've used `subprocess.Popen()` with Rhino and Rhino stays open until I close it manually. I do not understand why the behavior is different with xfoil.

I suspect it has something to do with the specific application's stdout but it's a wild guess. Hopefully it is possible to do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is when you call `communicate()` with the `input` parameter, the call will close `stdin`, which terminates the *xfoil.exe* process. Try the following instead of calling `communicate()`:

```
xfoil.stdin.write(actions)
xfoil.stdin.flush()
```

After that, the process continues until you exit your script.

## Update

If you want the xfoil project to continue even after your script ends, please look into pexpect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I ommited to specify that I am working on Windows, and ```pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn()``` does not seem to work with xfoil. I will check if I can make it work on Linux once I get time.